# How to combine scss files in one, not using @import in them, after require.context and before loaders?

Tags: webpack, sass

I am doing a project on an internship, and I was asked to remove all imports of scss files.

I use the ui-kit, in which all the scss files are imported into the main scss-file. This main file is imported into the js-file.

Webpack starts with a js file, converts files in a bundle. I need to get rid of import files.

for this i used the following code

```
function importAll (r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

importAll (require.context ('./', true, /\.js$|scss$/));
```

In this approach, I ran into a problem - files are downloaded in an unknown order. But I need the `color.scss` file with variables(`$purple: #BC9CFF;`) in other files without `@imports`.

The second approach that I saw in colleagues work-files is that a file `color.scss` is `@import` into each file where it is needed. And with that `require.context` work well. But I think this is inconvenient and requires more code support.

Is it possible to combine all `.scss` files using `require.context` or another loader, before the `sass-loader` is applied to them?

Answer (score 0):

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-glob-importer

in main js

```
import './style.scss';
```

in style.scss

```
@import "./UI-kit/**/*.scss";
```

and in webpack config

```
const globImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');


    {
            test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        importer: globImporter()
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

but I put all the necessary files with variables up to those files that needed them